# How to evaluate the performance of the pose estimation of Hector_Mapping

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to know how to evaluate the estimated pose of the hector mapping. Im using IMU and Laser range finder as a sensor package. So, is there any method to valid/evaluate the performance of the estimated pose by hector_mapping. How to know if the estimated pose is accurate?? Any explicit or implicit method of the evaluattion of the hector_mapping pose???

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50639/how-to-evaluate-the-performance-of-the-pose-estimation-of-hector_mapping/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some approaches to evaluate SLAM algorithms.

The most basic measure is: Make a map an look at it.

There exist some quantitative methods:

- Some can be found in the program of a [SLAM evaluation workshop](http://slameval.willowgarage.com/workshop/).
- You can find some information for using [relations](http://kaspar.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7EslamEvaluation/index.php) as an evaluation measure.
- The Robocup Rescue League uses mapping fiducials to see how good a map is.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-12-17**:
Ok. Thanks. . Just a comment, IS there to find a documentation how the robot pose in Hector_mapping was obtained?? I used the pose of the hector _mapping to obtained other parameters like velocity, so would like to know more about iAlso to understand the relations of the sensor sources and the pose

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-12-17**:
My sensor package consist of IMU and laser range finder

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-18**:
Sure, they list the paper on the Wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A slightly stronger variation of the **make a map and look at it** method that dornhege described: make a map and overlay it (with the correct scaling) on a blueprint of your building. If you're in a university, you can typically get those from the Facilities and Operations people.

While this is not a quantitative method, it is straightforward and fairly informative.

Here's an example that we've used in a paper:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-17**:
That's a good point. For outdoor mapping Google Map -> Canny also works quite well. Fig. 5 in http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/publications/papers/kuemmerle09auro.pdf gives an example of a canny "map".